# Dynamic verb for Windows shell context/shortcut menu extension

Tags: c++, winapi, atl, shell-extensions

I'd like to create a dynamic verb (menu item) for the Windows shell context/shortcut menu. I want it to appear only for items under some (configurable) paths, and I would like to execute some code that communicates with a process through a named pipe.

How do I best achieve that nowadays?

In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shortcut-choose-method#preferred-dynamic-verb-methods), they list the preferred dynamic verb methods:

> #### Preferred Dynamic Verb Methods
>
> The following dynamic verb methods are preferred:
>
> | Verb type | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | Static verb (listed in the previous table) + Advanced Query Syntax (AQS) | This choice gets dynamic verb visibility. |
> | Windows 7 and later: `IExplorerCommand` | This choice enables a common implementation of verbs and explorer commands that are displayed in the command module in Windows Explorer. |
> | Windows 7 and later: `IExplorerCommandState` + static verb | This choice also gets dynamic verb visibility. It is a hybrid model where a simple in-process handler is used to compute if a given static verb should be displayed. This can be applied to all of the static verb implementation methods to achieve dynamic behavior and minimize the exposure of the in-process logic. `IExplorerCommandState` has the advantage of running on a background thread, and thereby avoids UI hangs. It is considerably simpler than `IContextMenu`. |

They go on to discourage implementing `IContextMenu`:

> #### Discouraged Dynamic Verb Methods
>
> `IContextMenu` is the most powerful but also the most complicated method to implement. It is based on in-process COM objects that run on the thread of the caller, which usually Windows Explorer but can be any application hosting the items. `IContextMenu` supports verb visibility, ordering, and custom drawing. Some of these features have been added to the static verb features, such as an icon to be associated with a command, and `IExplorerCommand` to deal with visibility.

Later in the documentation, they have a page about ["Customizing a Shortcut Menu Using Dynamic Verbs"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shortcut-menu-using-dynamic-verbs) which only treats with the `IContextMenu` family, the one that was discouraged above, and without any mention of the aforementioned encouraged methods.

Lately, Microsoft has also communicated that [`IExplorerCommand` will be required in Windows 11](https://blogs.windows.com/blog/2021/07/19/extending-the-context-menu-and-share-dialog-in-windows-11/) for an item to appear in the new context menu.

I have tried implementing `IExplorerCommand`, for which documentation is very poor, and here are my notes:

- It seems to require a static verb (registered in `shell`, not `shellex`), which it will modify.
- As a modifier of a static verb, it can change the title, the icon, and whether the item is grayed out or not, but it doesn't allow to hide the item (`ECS_HIDDEN` only grays out the item).

Is there really no way of hiding the menu item with `IExplorerCommand`?

Could `IExplorerCommandProvider` prevent from having to use a static verb? If so, how should it be implemented?

There is practically no information available on that interface. All I've found is a [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/main/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/shellextensibility/explorerdataprovider/FVCommands.cpp) where it is implemented as an object that is returned to `IShellFolder::CreateViewObject()`. I haven't dug further, but `IShellFolder` seems tedious to implement, and I don't how such an implementation would be registered. Anyway, that sample also implements `IContextMenu`.

How would multiple commands be handled by a single DLL with `IExplorerCommand`?

What is the current stance on using .NET (Core/5/6) for creating shell extensions? Is it [still discouraged](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130222-01/?p=5163) to use such runtimes for inproc servers?

Comment: Windows 11 still supports IContextMenu (with the "Show More Options" menu item). Forget about IShellFolder just for context menus this is only for Shell Namespace Extension. For 6, there's no news so far https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/dd758089(v=vs.85)

Comment: [Getting Dynamic Behavior for Static Verbs by Using Advanced Query Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/context-menu-handlers?redirectedfrom=MSDN#getting-dynamic-behavior-for-static-verbs-by-using-advanced-query-syntax): Use the AppliesTo to specify the conditions under which the item is shown (and if it doesn't apply, the item is hidden). Another way to filter the items is to [use item attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/context-menu-handlers?redirectedfrom=MSDN#using-item-attributes).

Comment: @SimonMourier It does support IContextMenu, but I'd like it to appear in the first menu (it is one of the legitimate cases for that)

Comment: @RaymondChen I need to run some custom code to determine whether or not to show the item. Specifically to detect whether a process is running and whether that path is part of a dynamic set of folders that are relevant for that item. I don't believe that query syntax is able to do that.

Comment: Have you found a way to hide the item when implementing `IExplorerCommand` (`ECS_HIDDEN` also doesn't work here)? I've tried the AppliesTo with AQS as outlined by @RaymondChen, but it doesn't seem to have any effect when using with, e.g., `System.FileExtension:=".mp3"`

Comment: @fhe Not yet, I just went for `IContextMenu` as the conditions to display the menu item in my case cannot even begin to be expressed with AQS, and `IExplorerCommand.GetState()` just grays the menu item out at best despite the name `ECS_HIDDEN` of the flag.

Comment: Looks like that ECS_HIDDEN works properly (menu item hides instead of graying out) only if empty 'CommandStateSync' also set in registry. 

```
HKCR\AllFileSystemObjects\shell\<verb>\@CommandStateSync = ''
HKCR\AllFileSystemObjects\shell\<verb>\@ExplorerCommandHandler = '<IExplorerCommand class id>'
```